# read data from a json document using sql query

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to query data from the below json document using Azure SQL with the following query and see no data retrieved. The below SQL query works most of the time but every once in a while we recieve json documents which are not in the usual json structure we receive and this happens to be one of those edge cases. This json looks valid but for some reason unable to read data.

***json***

```
[{
        "value": [{
                "Id": 123,
                "Year": 2001,
                "Name": "abc"
            },
            {
                "Id": 234,
                "Year": 2001,
                "Name": "bcd"
            }
        ],
        "Count": 2
    },
    {
        "value": [{
                "Id": 123,
                "Year": 2002,
                "Name": "abc"
            },
            {
                "Id": 234,
                "Year": 2002,
                "Name": "bcd"
            }
        ],
        "Count": 2
    }
]
```

***Query:***

```
SELECT jsond.*
FROM OPENROWSET (
        bulk 'adls/test/test.json',
        data_source = 'datalake',
        format = 'csv',
        fieldterminator ='0x0b',
        fieldquote = '0x0b',
        rowterminator = '0x0b'
    ) 
    WITH (doc nvarchar(max)) AS ROWS
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (doc, '$.value')
        WITH (
    [Id] INT,
    [Year] INT,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(200)
    ) AS jsond
```

Please find the json document that works below.

```
{
    "value": [{
            "Id": 123,
            "Year": 2003,
            "Name": "abc"
        },
        {
            "Id": 234,
            "Year": 2003,
            "Name": "bcd"
        },
        {
            "Id": 345,
            "Year": 2003,
            "Name": "cde"
        }
    ],
    "Count": 3
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample that works with your query?

Comment: Why are you supplying all those delimited file-related options when specifying `openrowset(bulk ...)`? Is it really a JSON formatted file or just one with a .json extension?

Comment: It actually is a json formatted file. Also, If I were to use `OPENJSON` how do I pass the BLOB storage path from Azure SQL Database?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I wasn't able to make it work with `OPENJSON` as a work around when I tried `OPENROWSET` with csv format it worked.

Comment: `SELECT @json = T.c
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK '<path'>, SINGLE_CLOB) AS T(c)` I run into error `File cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another process.`

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft please find OP updated with working json.

Comment: `File cannot be opened because it does not exist or it is used by another process.` to resolve this error you can assign `Storage Blob Data Reader` or `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role to you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the ***Contributor*** role, able to run the query successfully with the below sample Json.

[image]

***Sample JSON***

```json
[{
"Id": 123,
"Year": 2001,
"Name": "abc"
},
{
"Id": 234,
"Year": 2001,
"Name": "bcd"
}
]
```

***Query :***

```json
Create  table jsondata( Id NCHAR(1000), year  NCHAR(500), Name  NCHAR(500) )
INSERT  INTO jsondata
SELECT id,year,name  FROM  OPENROWSET(
BULK  'test.json',
DATA_SOURCE =  'YourDataSource',
SINGLE_CLOB
) AS DataFile
cross  apply openjson(BulkColumn)
WITH (
[Id] INT,[Year] INT,[Name] NVARCHAR(20)) AS mydata;
select  *  from jsondata
```

***Output :***
[image]

- In Storage Account => Containers => change the access level to `Container (anonymous read access for containers and blobs)`

[image]

- Make sure that you have uploaded the JSON file in the `location` and is not in use.